# ReSharper interface naming

Tags: c#, resharper

In ReSharper, if I using the "Implement Interface" action on a class it creates a region named  `Implementation of IInterface`.  However, if I implement the interface manually then run a code cleanup, it wraps my interface members in a region named `IInterface Members`.

Why does it use two different naming conventions?  If there a way to standardize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the R# docs for [Reordering Type Members](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Reordering_Type_Members.html), the code clean up should reorder and wrap the implemented interface in a named region:

[image: R# ImplementsInterface XML Rules]

> This XML code matches members that implement an interface, surrounds
>   them with regions and sorts by the name of the implemented interface.
>   The ${ImplementsInterface} variable contains the name of the interface
>   being implemented. If you do not want to insert regions around
>   interface implementations, remove the Group tag and ReSharper will
>   just sort members according to the name of the interface they are
>   implementing.

Check your settings and see if you may have overridden the default behavior. On the other hand, I have not personally testing the code clean up with the reordering and region wrapping, so this is somewhat of a best guess. But, hopefully it can point you in the right direction.

**Edit**
After reviewing the documentation in more detail and exploring all the editable templates with R#, I don't think there is a way to edit the text for the region's label.

I decompiled the `JetBrains.ReSharper.Feature.Services.CSharp.dll` and found what I believe to the be the source of the region's label:

- Namespace: `JetBrains.ReSharper.Feature.Services.CSharp.Generate`
- Class: `CSharpGeneratorContext`
- Method: `InsertWithRegions` or `CSharpGeneratorContext`

Both methods have the string `"Implementation of " + <some code>` embedded in the dll, so it appears you will not be able to edit the default text.

Comment: That is what I have and that is where the `IInterface Members` region comes from.  I actually prefer that wording.  As of now, I am trying to figure out where `Implementation of IInterface` comes from.  For now, I figured out how to disable that region, but I would prefer to customize that region's label.

Comment: See edit; it appears the default text is embedded in one of the R# dll's.